# eas build Package issue ("Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js is linked" error message persisting)

Tags: react-native, expo, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I've recently made a local build for my Amplify/React Native/Expo project using *eas build*.  Within the local build, when attempting to sign in using Amplify's *Auth.signIn()* feature, I am receiving the error: *Could not find a native getRandomBase64 implementation.  Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js is linked.*

A quick search suggested that this problem could be fixed by installing the *amazon-cognito-identity-js* package, which I did (*yarn add amazon-cognito-identity-js*).  Unfortunately, this did not resolve the error.  Are there additional steps that I need to take to fix this that I have yet to do?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by running eas build again and creating another build.